# T-SQL max date and min date between two date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

First, thanks for your time and your help!

I have two tables:

Table 1

```
PersId     name       lastName   city
---------------------------------------
1          John       Smith      Tirana
2          Leri       Nice       Tirana
3          Adam       fortsan    Tirana
```

Table 2

```
Id       PersId      salesDate
--------------------------------------------
1         1          2017-01-22 08:00:40 000
2         2          2017-01-22 09:00:00 000
3         1          2017-01-22 10:00:00 000
4         1          2017-01-22 20:00:00 000
5         3          2017-01-15 09:00:00 000
6         1          2017-01-21 09:00:00 000
7         1          2017-01-21 10:00:00 000
8         1          2017-01-21 18:55:00 000
```

I would like to see the first recent sales between two dates according to each city for **each day** I want to bring it empty if I do not have a sale

```
 SalesDate > '2017-01-17 09:00:00 000' 
 and SalesDate < '2017-01-23 09:00:00 000'
```

Table 2, id = 5 because the record is not in the specified date range

If I wanted my results to look like

```
Id      PersId     MinSalesDate                 MaxSalesDate             City 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         1        2017-01-22 08:00:40 000      2017-01-22 20:00:00 000 Tirana
2         2        2017-01-22 09:00:00 000      null                   Tirana
3         3        null                         null                   Tirana
4         1        2017-01-21 09:00:00 000      2017-01-21 18:55:00 000   Tirana
```

Comment: Start with a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, please tag correctly; you've tagged MySQL and SQL Server & T-SQL here. MySQL and SQL are totally different, and MySQL does not use T-SQL. I've removed these tags, however, please update your post for the correct RDBMS.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: i m using MS SQL Server

Comment: jarlh i know start a left join but how can i do ?

Comment: How can that be by city?  You have the same city listed 3 times.

Comment: Why is the city being sold?

Answer (score 3):

You dont identify how to get ID in the result.  You appear to just want Row_Number().  I will leave that out, but this should get you started.  You may have to work out conversion issues in the data range check, and I havent checked the query for syntax errors, I will leave that to you.

```
Select T1.PersId, City
     , Min(T2.salesDate) MinSalesDate
     , Max(T2.salesDate) MaxSalesDate
   From Table1 T1
   Left Join Table2 T2 
     On T1.PersId = T2.PersId 
    And T2.salesDate Between '2017-01-17 09:00:00 000' And < '2017-01-23 09:00:00 000'
   Group BY T1.PersId, T2.City
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean about ROW_NUMBER. I don't see anything in the OP that would indicate that. I would avoid using BETWEEN as it can be a little confusing, especially with dates. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common But aside from the obvious syntax error this is the right answer.

Comment: The bottom answer is working. but I could not vote because my score was not enough.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following using row_number to get min and max sale dates:

```
        SELECT 
            T2.Id, T1.PersId, T2.MIN_salesDate, T2.MAX_salesDate, T1.City
        FROM Table1 T1
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT MIN(Id) as Id, PersId, MIN(salesDate) as MIN_salesDate, MAX(salesDate) as MAX_salesDate 
            FROM
            (
                SELECT 
                     *
                    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersId ORDER BY salesDate ASC) as RNKMIN
                    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersId ORDER BY salesDate DESC) as RNKMAX 
                FROM Table2 T2 
                WHERE salesDate Between '2017-01-17 09:00:00 000' And '2017-01-23 09:00:00 000'
            ) temp
            WHERE RNKMIN = 1 or RNKMAX = 1
            GROUP BY PersId
        ) T2
        on T1.PersId = T2.PersId
```

Comment: sorry dude . my score is not enough

Comment: my779 
I have added the sample table above, but I want to do the query separately for each day. Can you help me?